# Nivelar Array PHP

Tags: php, array

Preciso colocar esse `array` todo em um mesmo nível, tentei dessa forma, mas não consegui deixar todos no mesmo nível, segue abaixo a entrada, saída e o código que tentei.

Entrada

```
[
    (int) 0 => [
        'id' => (int) 1,
        'nome' => 'Administrador'
    ],
    (int) 1 => [
        (int) 0 => [
            'id' => (int) 17,
            'nome' => 'Administrador > Revenda 1'
        ],
        (int) 1 => [
            (int) 0 => [
                'id' => (int) 20,
                'nome' => 'Administrador > Revenda 1 > Revenda Teste > 1'
            ],
            (int) 1 => [
                (int) 0 => [
                    'id' => (int) 25,
                    'nome' => 'Administrador > Revenda 1 > Revenda Teste > 1 > Revenda Teste 2 - 1'
                ]
            ],
            (int) 2 => [
                'id' => (int) 21,
                'nome' => 'Administrador > Revenda 1 > Reventa Teste > 2'
            ],
            (int) 3 => [
                'id' => (int) 22,
                'nome' => 'Administrador > Revenda 1 > Revenda Teste  > 3'
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
```

Preciso dessa saída:

```
[
(int) 0 => [
    'id' => (int) 1,
    'nome' => 'Administrador'
],
(int) 1 => [
    'id' => (int) 17,
    'nome' => 'Administrador > Revenda 1'
],
(int) 2 => [
    'id' => (int) 20,
    'nome' => 'Administrador > Revenda 1 > Revenda Teste > 1'
],
(int) 3 => [
    'id' => (int) 25,
    'nome' => 'Administrador > Revenda 1 > Revenda Teste > 1 > Revenda Teste 2 - 1'
],
(int) 4 => [
    'id' => (int) 21,
    'nome' => 'Administrador > Revenda 1 > Reventa Teste > 2'
],
(int) 5 => [
    'id' => (int) 22,
    'nome' => 'Administrador > Revenda 1 > Revenda Teste  > 3'
]
]
```

Meu código:

```
    public function organizarMenu($menu){

    foreach($menu as $key => $val){
        if(isset($val["id"])){
            $newmenu[] = ['id' => $val['id'], 'nome' => $val['nome']];
        }else{
            $newmenu[] = $this->organizarMenu($val);
        }

    }
    return $newmenu;
}
```

Comment: _"mas falta algo"_ o que que falta?

Comment: Falta a saída ficar da forma que pretendo.

Comment: Eu entendi a questão. Veja a minha resposta se te atende.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Essa função recursiva irá solucionar seu problema:

Considerando que `$array_base` é seu array incial apresentado e `$array_final` é a saída desejada.

```
<?php
    $array_base = array(
        0=>array('id'=>1, 'nome'=>'Administrador'),
        1=>array(
            0=>array('id'=>17, 'nome'=>'Administrador > Revenda 1'),
            1=>array(
                0=>array('id'=>20, 'nome'=>'Administrador > Revenda 1 > Revenda Teste > 1'),
                1=>array(
                    0=>array('id'=>25, 'nome'=>'Administrador > Revenda 1 > Revenda Teste > 1 > Revenda Teste 2 - 1'),
                ),
                2=>array('id'=>20, 'nome'=>'Administrador > Revenda 1 > Revenda Teste > 2'),
                3=>array('id'=>20, 'nome'=>'Administrador > Revenda 1 > Revenda Teste > 3'),
            ),
        ),
    );

    $array_final = array();

    foreach ($array_base as $resultado) {
        if(isset($resultado['id'])){
            $array_final[]= $resultado;
        }else{
            $array_final = subnivel($resultado, $array_final);
        }
    }

    var_dump($array_final);exit;

    function subnivel($array_subnivel, $array_final){
        foreach ($array_subnivel as $subnivel) {
            if(isset($subnivel['id'])){
                $array_final[]= $subnivel;
            }else{
                $array_final = subnivel($subnivel, $array_final);
            }
        }
        return $array_final;
    }
?>
```

O `var_dump` irá retornar um array unidimensional de tamano 6, com cada array dentro dele contendo `id` e `nome`.

É possível ainda ver o código funcionando com a saída desejada em: [www.ideone.com/cjNrRF](http://www.ideone.com/cjNrRF)

Comment: É possível ainda ver o código funcionando com a saída desejada em: https://ideone.com/cjNrRF

Comment: Perfeito man!!! Exatamente isso.

Comment: Obrigado! @DavidAlves

Comment: Que bom que funcionou ;D

Comment: Coloque o link do Ideone na resposta que faz mais sentido, e ajuda quem queira testar o código proposto por si

Comment: Boa @Isac editei a resposta.